# Post request executed in for loop in Jenkins pipeline throws error org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap$ListOrderedMapEntry

Tags: curl, jenkins, post

I am executing POST request using curl inside a for loop in Jenkins pipeline. Input data changes in each iteration. I am getting following exception:

```
org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap$ListOrderedMapEntry
```

The exception remains same on using httpRequest plugin. Please suggest solutions.

```
//input key has a list of IDs
for(inputKey in configs.map){
  len_val = inputKey.value.size()
  //Each ID is used as input for POST request
  for(i=0; i < len_val; i++){
      input_request = "curl --request POST --url" + configs.url + 
                       inputKey.value[i]"
      def response = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "${input_request}")
      echo response
  }
}
```

Expected result is "Request is accepted"

Comment: Can you please post the full exception text?

Comment: an exception which occurred:
 in field com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.BlockScopeEnv.locals
 in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable@671f97cc
 in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.program
Caused: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.commons.collections.map.ListOrderedMap$ListOrderedMapEntry
 at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:926)